# How to break line in python function description?

Tags: python, pycharm

I've tried to find the solution on how to break the line in a python function description, but there were none that worked for me.
I have such a function:

[image]

But the description that shows when I am hovering that function shows continous chain of characters and there are no breaks, like below:
[image]
How do I do breaklines in the function desc?

EDIT:
Due to the request I am posting the code(when pasting the code indentation has broken):

```py
from pandas import PandasDataFrame
def calculate_input_types(price_df: PandasDataFrame, calculate_all: bool = True, *, input_type: dict) -> PandasDataFrame:
    """
    :param price_df: price_df: Dataframe containing Open, Close, High, Low, Volume price data.
    :param calculate_all: Boolean value True or False, if True function calculates all possible input types.
        HL2, HLC3, OHLC4, HLCC4, if False function calculates only chosen input types, must pass a dictionary.
    :param input_type: Optional argument, mandatory if calculate_all is set to False. A dictionary should posses input
        types as keys and one-hot encoded value of 1 if the input type is to be calculated
        or 0 if the input type shouldn't be calculated.
        Example of input_type:
        input_type = {
                HL2 : 1,
                HLC3 : 1,
                OHLC4 : 0,
                HLCC4 : 1
        }
        This type of input calculates only HL2, HLC3 and HLCC4 since those are set to 1 and OHLC4 is set to 0.

    :return: Dataframe with calculated input types.
    """
    return 'apple'
```

Comment: What do you mean by "continuous chain of characters"?

Comment: \n have you tried?

Comment: @statlad yes, but it just shows /n in the description

Comment: @TheMyth, what i meant by that is that there are no breaklines in the description where I meant them to be, i.e. the line that was meant to show in the new line is in the same line as the previous sentence.

Comment: Does this help: [quickinfo does not show newlines in docstring](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-17532)

Comment: it's a ide issue, not python one, in python obj.__doc__ work fine as intended

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to somewhat fix the problem:

```py
from pandas import PandasDataFrame


def calculate_input_types(price_df: PandasDataFrame, calculate_all: bool = True, *, input_type: dict) -> PandasDataFrame:
    """
    Example of input_type:\n
    input_type = {
        HL2 : 1,\n
        HLC3 : 1,\n
        OHLC4 : 0,\n
        HLCC4 : 1\n
    }\n
    :param price_df: price_df: Dataframe containing Open, Close, High, Low, Volume price data.
    :param calculate_all: Boolean value True or False, if True function calculates all possible input types.
        HL2, HLC3, OHLC4, HLCC4, if False function calculates only chosen input types, must pass a dictionary.
    :param input_type: Optional argument, mandatory if calculate_all is set to False. A dictionary should posses input
        types as keys and one-hot encoded value of 1 if the input type is to be calculated
        or 0 if the input type shouldn't be calculated.
    :return: Dataframe with calculated input types.
        This type of input calculates only HL2, HLC3 and HLCC4 since those are set to 1 and OHLC4 is set to 0.
    """
    return 'apple'
```

[image: Pycharm Document]

Comment: Ok, I have fixed my mistake, but unfortunately it did not solved the problem.
Description still shows itself in one continous line, breaking only if it reaches the container border.
Is it that pycharm does not allow for custom breaklines in function description?